# Rails getting activity feed that only involves current_user

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, notifications, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm using the public_activity gem on my rails app to get all of the current_users followers activity. It works great but I'd prefer to get only the activity that relates to the current_user so it's more of a Notification system than just Activities.

Here is what I have so far in my activities controller

```
@activities_all = PublicActivity::Activity.order("created_at desc").where(owner_type: "User", owner_id: current_user.followed_users.map {|u| u.id}).all
@activities = @activities_all.group_by { |t| t.created_at.beginning_of_day }
```

As stated before, this gives all the activities that the current_user's followers do (like create/comment on a post). I'd prefer it if I could get it to work where it's all the activities where my followers interact with my posts, etc. So when a user comments and that comment is on my post, then i want that to be part of @activities.

At first glance, I would figure this is another query I just cannot figure out the query (if query is the correct way).

Here is some front end code if that will help

```
<% @activities.sort.each do |day, activities| %>
  <h6><%= day.strftime("%B %d") %></h6>
    <% for activity in activities %>
      <% if activity.trackable %>
        <div class="activity">
          <p>
            <%= activity_user_image(activity.owner) %>
            <%= activity_user_name(activity.owner) if activity.owner %>
            <%= render_activity activity %> 
            <span><%= activity.created_at.strftime("%I:%M %p") %></span>
          </p>
        </div>
     <% end %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Thanks for the help all. Happy Holidays

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case anyone else have this question down the road, I found the answer

First, I added a recipient to each activity.

```
if @comment.save
  @comment.create_activity :create, owner: current_user, recipient: @design.user
end
```

Then i added another query to the activities

```
@activities_all = PublicActivity::Activity.order("created_at desc").where(recipient_id: current_user).where("owner_id not in (?)", current_user).all
```

Answer (score 0):

Not really sure about your relationships, but something like this should work:

```
@user_activities = PublicActivity::Activity.order("created_at desc").where(owner_type: "User", owner_id: current_user.id).all
```

Comment: That just shows the current_user's activity, instead of showing all the user's activities that happen on the current_user's posts

Comment: I think i need to figure out how to add a recipient to the activities to get the answer

Comment: Looks like I figured it out by adding a recipient_id to each activity. Still have to finish it to make sure it works, but it's looking like it's going to. Thanks for taking a look at it

Comment: No stress, sorry I couldn't be more help.